# Iterative solving for unknowns in a fluids problem

Tags: algorithm

I am a Mechanical engineer with a computer scientist question. This is an example of what the equations I'm working with are like:

> x = √((y-z)×2/r)
>   z = f×(L/D)×(x/2g)
>   f = something crazy with x in it
>   etc…(there are more equations with x in it)

#### The situation is this:

I need r to find x, but I need x to find z. I also need x to find f which is a part of finding z. So I guess a value for x, and then I use that value to find r and f. Then I go back and use the value I found for r and f to find x. I keep doing this until the guess and the calculated are the same.

#### My question is:

How do I get the computer to do this? I've been using mathcad, but an example in another language like C++ is fine.

Comment: You won't just get a solution here, you're going to have to make an effort first. Post your code, we'll help you fine-tune and debug.

Comment: And sometimes I just wonder why there are people paid for proving existence and uniqueness of solutions, Lipschitz conditions for convergence of such algorithms... Never mind, just go to StackOverflow and have your problem solved for free!

Comment: Post your "crazy things" and let's see them

Comment: What your are asking for is normally a full semester class at university level. There are multiple methods to solve such equations and whole books written about this. Do you want to understand one or more iterative approximation algorithms for this, of just to solve the equations?

Comment: I would like to understand it so that I can solve other problems like it.

Comment: It would appear that the poster knows how to solve the problem just fine with pen and paper... I think they're just looking for an algorithm to use for it.

Comment: So you want to understand how to algorithmically solve a *system of non-linear equations* through a single question in StackOverflow? Even the "simple" Gauss–Seidel method for linear equation systems is a whole chapter in most books - and only if you don't go too deep in convergence theory etc. and its implementation details...

Comment: I mean understand the problem, but I would like to understand how to solve it using code.

Comment: @thkala: if OP has strong reasons to think the solution is unique and that a simple relaxation approach like this should work, why not. He is not asking for an algorithm, he is asking us to write the code, which is different. This question should be closed.

Comment: @luminara19131: You understand the _problem_. OK, that's good. Do you have an iterative algorithm to solve it that you _also_ understand? Something that you can do limited iterations on paper for?

Comment: Yeah. I just thought it would be faster to use the computer, and I wanted to learn something new. It's cool. I will do it the old fashioned way. Cheers

Comment: @Alexandre-c "How do I get the computer to do this?" is clearly asking for an algorithm. The system of equations wasn't actually posted, so it's really hard to imply that OP wanted a full solution. Your ad-hominem attack on the OP is also quite inappropriate. You should also note that the OP is a SHE, not a HE.

Comment: It _is_ faster to use the computer. But in that case the correct question for StackOverflow would be "I want to implement the generalized Newton–Raphson method for equation systems. I have already written this <insert code>, but it does not compile/do what I expect/ever end"

Comment: as @thkala said you can search google to find answer, I think no one here helps you to write code,, first show your attempt.

Comment: @Jon: where do you see ad hominem attacks ? I never meant to be rude. I just point out that this is not a real question, and OP is *not* asking for an algorithm, but an implementation of her attempt at an algorithm (which could or not work, provided we know and analyze the equations better). I assume solving the 1D equations that result is the easy part.

Comment: @Jon: Yet the OP is not asking just for an algorithm. They're asking for an algorithm written in a _language_ i.e. a program. And since no specific algorithm is mentioned in the question, I'd guess they actually want both.

Comment: Come on! Here is someone that wants to learn! He/She is not asking "how 2 off log in appz "

Comment: @Alexandre-c Go back and read your first response to the question. If you see a first time poster who's not familiar with computer science, you may want to be a bit more gentle. Perhaps help them ask their question as @thkala has been trying to do.

Comment: @belisarius: With more info, we could give it a try.

Comment: And the first piece of necessary information would be exactly what the OP wants to do. The answer to "I want to solve this using a computer" is a whole knowledge field.

Comment: @Alexandre Sure! My first comment (the third from above) asked for that. But I guess the OP flew away under the menaces of interning a full semester to solve an eq system

Comment: @belisarius Note that the OP has no problem solving the equation on paper. After reading the comments here, I can understand why OP gave up.

Comment: @Jon Yup. This is weird. SO is full of questions whose answer are within the reach of two words typed in Google. And when someone has a tough one, and deserves some help, we come to this ...

Comment: @belisarius: I have no problem with tough questions, as long as they provide solid information on what is the context ("I know how to ... and I want to..."), what is there ("I attempted to ... and I have managed to...") and what is missing ("I have no idea how to..."). In this case we only had the first and that was relatively unclear in my opinion, which is why I tried to get more information...

Comment: @thkala You are right, but. The OP is not a programmer or CS by profession, so he/she doesn't know how many different algs for solving eqs systems are there in the wild. Also, it's not clear for him/her how much you have to understand before answering, and no wonder if "numerical stability" and "precision" are outside his vocabulary. Anyway I think he/she did nothing to deserve this comment: _Never mind, just go to StackOverflow and have your problem solved for free!_ posted above.

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing you should do faced with iterative algorithms is write down *on paper* the sequence that will result from your idea:

Eg.:

```
 x_0 = ..., f_0 = ..., r_0 = ...
 x_1 = ..., f_1 = ..., r_1 = ...

 ...

 x_n = ..., f_n = ..., r_n = ...
```

Now, you have an idea of what you should implement (even if you don't know *how*). If you don't manage to find a closed form expression for one of the x_i, r_i or whatever_i, you will need to solve one dimensional equations numerically. This will imply more work.

Now, for the implementation part, if you never wrote a program, you should seriously ask someone live who can help you (or hire an intern and have him write the code). We cannot help you beginning from scratch with, eg. C programming, but we are willing to help you with *specific problems* which should arise when you write the program.

Please note that your algorithm is not guaranteed to converge, even if you strongly think there is a unique solution. Solving non linear equations is a difficult subject.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that mathcad has many abstractions for iterative algorithms without the need to actually implement them directly using a "lower level" language. Perhaps this question is better suited for the mathcad forums at:

http://communities.ptc.com/index.jspa

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mathcad, it has the functionality built in. It is called *solve block*.

Start with the keyword "given"

**Given**

define the guess values for all unknowns

**x:=2
f:=3
r:=2
...**

define your constraints

**x = √((y-z)×2/r)**

**z = f×(L/D)×(x/2g)**

**f = something crazy with x in it**

**etc…(there are more equations with x in it)**

calculate the solution

**find(x, y, z, r, ...)=**

Check Mathcad help or Quicksheets for examples of the exact syntax.

Comment: @luminara19131 this looks like your answer to me

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is this pseudo-code:

```
X = startingX;
lastF = Infinity;
F = 0;
tolerance = 1e-10;
while ((lastF - F)^2 > tolerance)
{
    lastF = F;
    X = ?;
    R = ?;
    F = FunctionOf(X,R);
}
```

This may not do what you expect at all. It may give a valid but nonsense answer or it may loop endlessly between alternate wrong answers.

This is standard substitution to convergence. There are more advanced techniques like [DIIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIIS) but I'm not sure you want to go there. I found this article while figuring out if I want to go there.

In general, it really pays to think about how you can transform your problem into an easier problem.

In my experience it is better to pose your problem as a univariate bounded root-finding problem and use [Brent's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method) if you can

Next worst option is multivariate minimization with something like BFGS.

Iterative solutions are horrible, but are more easily solved once you think of them as X2 = f(X1) where X is the input vector and you're trying to reduce the difference between X1 and X2.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters have noted, the mathematical aspects of your question are beyond the scope of the help you can expect here, and are even beyond the help you could be offered based on the detail you posted.

However, I think that even if you understood the mathematics thoroughly there are computer science aspects to your question that should be addressed.

When you write your code, try to make organize it into functions that depend only upon the parameters you are passing in to a subroutine.  So write a subroutine that takes in values for y, z, and r and returns you x.  Make another that takes in f,L,D,G and returns z. Now you have testable routines that you can check to make sure they are computing correctly.  Check the input values to your routines in the routines - for instance in computing x you will get a divide by 0 error if you pass in a 0 for r. Think about how you want to handle this.

If you are going to solve this problem interatively you will need a method that will decide, based on the results of one iteration, what the values for the next iteration will be.  This also should be encapsulated within a subroutine.  Now if you are using a language that allows only one value to be returned from a subroutine (which is most common computation languages C, C++, Java, C#) you need to package up all your variables into some kind of data structure to return them.  You could use an array of reals or doubles, but it would be nicer to choose to make an object and then you can reference the variables by their name and not their position (less chance of error).

Another aspect of iteration is knowing when to stop.  Certainly you'll do so when you get a solution that converges.  Make this decision into another subroutine.  Now when you need to change the convergence criteria there is only one place in the code to go to.  But you need to consider other reasons for stopping - what do you do if your solution starts diverging instead of converging?  How many iterations will you allow the run to go before giving up?

Another aspect of iteration of a computer is round-off error.  Mathematically 10^40/10^38 is 100.  Mathematically 10^20 + 1 > 10^20.  These statements are not true in most computations.  Your calculations may need to take this into account or you will end up with numbers that are garbage.  This is an example of a cross-cutting concern that does not lend itself to encapsulation in a subroutine.

I would suggest that you go look at the Python language, and the pythonxy.com extensions.  There are people in the associated forums that would be a good resource for helping you learn how to do iterative solving of a system of equations.

Comment: Not true, there are plenty of mathematicians here I'm sure. I've got a PhD in maths and I know there are an awful lot of more capable mathematicians than myself here on SO.